# Error sending e-mail when using webform

Tags: webforms

I know there are already several posts about this subject, but I couldn't find a similar problem.
I have several webforms on my site. Each webform has an email action, sending an e-mail to only one recipient. When submitting the form, I get a "Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists." message. However the e-mail is sent without any problem. When looking into the dblog, I see an error:

> Error sending e-mail (from blabla@mydomain.com to )

Note that the e-mail I wrote is not the real one ;-).
So it seems that my site is trying to send an e-mail to an empty recipient (in addition to the correct recipient). If I look into the database, in the "webform_emails" table I see 1 single line for my webform, corresponding to the right recipient. So, why does webform try to send an e-mail to nothing??
Any idea?
Thanks,
Pierre

Comment: Welcome @P Daubresse to the Drupal Answers.  Is this regarding Drupal 7 or 8 ? Can we assume that regular emails (password recovery) work ? can you give a little more detail about your setup ?

Comment: Hi Giorgos. I found out the problem. I have a rule enabled, that sends an e-mail. This rule is triggered when a webform is saved. I added a condition on the rule, in order to limit to a specific webform, but it doesn't work. Si I simply need to fix the condition. Best regards.

Comment: Glad you found the problem @P Daubresse

Answer (score 0):

My problem is not due to webforms but to a rule that is triggered when a webform is saved. The condition I put in the rule needs to be fixed, in order to run only for a specific webform.